# how to change the display size of the firefox-os simulator?

Tags: simulator, firefox-os

I'm running `Firefox OS 2.0` simulator via Firefox WebIDE.

The [MDN Firefox OS doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator) only states 320x480 pixels for the device size, but some of the supported [devices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Phone_guide/Phone_specs) have much higher resolutions available.

I would like to be able to change the device screen size so I can test my application in the simulator with different display sizes - how is this done?

Here is an image from the WebIDE showing the `Device Settings` disabled:

[image]

I'm using Firefox version 39.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulator configuration was recently [made available](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1156834) in Firefox 42.  This gives you access to options like the window size:

[image: WebIDE Simulator Options]

Switching to Nightly to access Firefox 42 is likely the best path for now, since a number of related bugs were recently fixed in that version.